# highchart Series giving error inside while loop in php

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

```
series: [{
    data: [

        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 9), 71.5],
         [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 9), 77.5],
         [Date.UTC(2010, 6, 9), 77.5],
         [Date.UTC(2010, 7, 9), 77.5],
         [Date.UTC(2010, 8, 9), 77.5],

     ]

}]
```

The up onve is the simple series of pie chart its working fine but when i put it inside while loop with $date it does't work like this :

```
       <?php
      while($row_query=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_chart)){

  $datetime =$row_query['ptime'];
  $plschart =  $row_query['pls'];

  $data = date('Y, m, d',strtotime($datetime ));



    ?>
        [Date.UTC(<?php echo $date; ?>), <?php echo $plschart;?>],


    <?php  } ?> 

     ]

}]
```

Note:$date output is like this 2016, 09, 06, if i manually put that date its working fine even with $plschart but with $date its not showing anything so problem is with putting directly $date. Thank in advance.

Comment: Why is data an array of arrays? Also, what has this to do with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

its Solved, instead of echo $data i echo $date. solved Thanks all